# Select ALL records from one table and display 0's for rows not matching a condition in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

For the purposes of this question I have 2 tables.

1. Requests: Timestamp, SessionID, Site, CampaignID, TagName
2. Events: Timestamp, SessionID, CampaignID, TagName, InteractionID

Most of the fields are varchar and allow nulls because these are flat files imported from custom server logs and sometimes unexpected characters can leak into one field from another - I can't control that. My requirement is to provide a Site report detailing the Unique Sites, Ad Tag, & Count of times each ad(Tag) ran on each site, along with a count of user interactions with the ad, plus a count of clicks, which is defined as one of 3 interaction_id's (1,2,or 3).

Running a separate query to check the actual data in Requests:

```
SELECT Convert(CHAR(10), r.Timestamp,101) AS [Date]
    , r.Site, r.CampaignID
    , r.TagName, Count(r.TagName) AS TagCount

FROM Requests AS r
WHERE r.CampaignID = 1901 
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(10), r.Timestamp,101) , r.Site, r.CampaignID, r.TagName
ORDER BY [Date], r.Site, r.CampaignID, r.TagName
```

yields:

```
Date        Site    CampaignID   TagName TagCount
09/01/2013  Site1   1901          Tag1    61
09/01/2013  Site1   1901          Tag2    3703
09/01/2013  Site1   1901          Tag3    279
09/01/2013  Site2   1901          Tag1    30
...
```

To get the count of interactions I tried...

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), r.Timestamp,101) AS [Date], r.Site, r.CampaignID, r.TagName, Count(r.TagName) As TagCount, Count(e.InteractionID) AS InteractionCount
FROM Requests AS r
LEFT JOIN Events as e ON r.SessionID = e.SessionID
WHERE r.CampaignID = 9101 
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(10), r.Timestamp,101) ,r.Site, r.CampaignID, r.TagName
ORDER BY [Date], r.Site, r.CampaignID, e.TagName
```

yields:

```
Date        Site    CampaignID  TagName TagCount    InteractionCount
09/01/2013  Site1   9101        Tag1    130         78
09/01/2013  Site1   9101        Tag2    3805        352
09/01/2013  Site1   9101        Tag3    307         53
09/01/2013  Site2   9101        Tag1    30          0
...
```

My questions/issues. TagCount has gone up, that surprises me. I can understand how it would go down as a result of the join condition, but why up? It seems to me that the first query should be counting all available records, the second shouldn't find more to count. It must be something I don't understand about a left join. So how do I get TagCount from Requests so that it just counts all of them, and then get InteractionCount from Events for each Site & TagName. I'm not familiar enough with SQL to come up with a sub-query that will achieve the right result but I guess that's where the answer lies.

The last part of my problem is Clicks

```
Where e.InteractionID = '1' OR e.InteractionID = '2' OR e.InteractionID = '3'
```

restricts my result set to only those records which contain clicks, but I need the rest of the records from the left side, with 0's if there are no clicks and the sum of the counts of any that meet those conditions.

I hope I've been clear about the problems, and I appreciate your time and energy, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason tag count is going up is because you are counting rows, not distinct values.  You can fix this by using `count(distinct)`.  The question is what is the right argument.  Obviously, `tagName` isn't the right argument, because you are grouping by that field.  A request Id would work, but it is not available.  This might work:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), r.Timestamp,101) AS [Date], r.Site, r.CampaignID, r.TagName,
       Count(distinct r.sID) As TagCount, Count(e.InteractionID) AS InteractionCount
FROM Requests r LEFT JOIN
     Events e
     ON r.SessionID = e.SessionID
WHERE r.CampaignID = 9101 
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(10), r.Timestamp,101) ,r.Site, r.CampaignID, r.TagName
ORDER BY [Date], r.Site, r.CampaignID, e.TagName;
```

In other words, when you do the join, you are getting duplicated rows from the `left join`.  These are being counting as multiples.

If the above doesn't work, you need to do the calculation as a subquery, then do the join:

```
select r.[Date], r.Site, r.CampaignID, r.TagName, r.TagCount,
       count(e.InteractionID) as InteractionCount
from (SELECT Convert(CHAR(10), r.Timestamp,101) AS [Date], r.Site, r.CampaignID
             r.TagName, Count(r.TagName) AS TagCount
      FROM Requests r
      WHERE r.CampaignID = 1901 
      GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(10), r.Timestamp, 101), r.Site, r.CampaignID, r.TagName
     ) r join
     events e
     ON r.SessionID = e.SessionID
ORDER BY [Date], r.Site, r.CampaignID, r.TagName;
```

Comment: I've tried that, but Count(distinct TagName) makes the entire column = 1. And I just checked, the count of rows doesn't change between the 2 results.

Comment: @JessieBoone . . . Duh.  You are grouping by that column, so it will always be 1.  See my revised answer.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Trying this one - theres a missing comma in the subquery after r.CampaignID, and r.SessionID doesn't exist in the subquery. not sure if I can just add it since I would have to group on it.

Comment: trying the modified top query in your answer I replaced `Count(distinct r.Timestamp)` with `Count(distinct r.SID)` and that works great :) Any help for adding the Clicks Column to this?

Comment: @JessieBoone . . . If clicks are in another table, you will need to aggregate them (or something) before doing the joins.

Comment: Clicks are calculated from Events just as Count of Interactions but with the condition that InteractionID = 1,2,or 3. These represent 3 types of click that can occur and as a sum they represent all clicks.

Answer (score 2):

if you timestamp is unique in groups, then:

```
select
    convert(char(10), r.Timestamp, 101) as [Date],
    r.Site, r.CampaignID, r.TagName,
    count(distinct r.SID) as TagCount,
    count(e.InteractionID) as InteractionCount,
    count(case when e.InteractionID in (1, 2, 3) then e.InteractionID end) as ClicksCount
from Requests as r
    left outer join Events e on e.SessionID = r.SessionID
where r.CampaignID = 9101 
group by
    convert(char(10), r.Timestamp, 101), r.Site, r.CampaignID, r.TagName
order by [Date], Site, CampaignID, TagName;
```

Comment: timestamp SHOULD be unique because its scale is 3 - but when I use `distinct r.Timestamp` my count is off by just a few. using `unique r.SID` in it's place gets me a count that matches my first test query. The left outer join gets me the same count of records and values as the left join - the one thing I am missing now is how to add a Clicks column to this result (see the last part of my question. I would +1 your answer since I've already selected an answer but I can't for points as of yet. Thanks :)

Comment: I wanted to be sure to try everything here - if you are going to take the time to answer my question then I should make sure I gleen what I can from it. There is a misplaced comma after tagCount in the outer select, after correcting that I get an error... `Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.` Perhaps because r.SessionID is contained in the group by of the subquery? not sure how to fix that.

Comment: yes, it looks like it's not possible - hard to create query without testing... Just in case, added ClicksCount to the query.

Comment: ah! awesome. haven't seen that use of case before quite like that. I was looking for a way to use a where clause in an aggregate, there it is! :) Someone please drop a driveby +1 on this for me!